# XMLGregorianCalendar 2010-12-21T08:55:17E-7+01:00 E-7. What does E-7 mean

Tags: java, soap

From a SOAP webservice, a date field is returned as the string:

```
2010-12-21T08:55:17E-7+01:00
```

which .NET has problems parsing. Jax has no problems with this. What does E-7 mean. And what can I do normalize it in a java server.

EDIT: I have a java server thats acts as a transistion from multiple servers with buggy timestamp. What can I do normalize it once it has been parsed by jax? .normalise() will give me UTC which I'm not sure I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ISO 8601 time you **always** deal with Z = Zulu for UTC, but there are other military time zones as well (not part of the standard):

http://www.navycs.com/militarytime.html

E is for Echo and means the time zone UTC + 5.

I have no explanation for the -7 and +01:00 parts though.

Edit: Updated the post to make clear Z is the only allowed notation for ISO 8601 times.

Comment: SOAP doesn't deal with Echo as far as I'm aware... only Zulu and time zone offsets. So I'd expect the +01:00 to be the offset - and I suspect the E-7 part is just a bug :(

Comment: Yeah +1:00 could be the offset and that does not mix well with E being +5:00. E-7 looks like the exponential notation of a floating number.

Comment: If Echo is the explanation, then this is an ISO date/time used in a context where an XML datetime is required.  The syntax of an XML datetime has this for the timezone component: `(('+' | '-') hh ':' mm) | 'Z'`,  Note that military zones (apart from Zulu) are not allowed.  I cannot find an online spec for ISO 8601 (sigh), but all indications are that it doesn't support military zones either.

Comment: I had a good laugh at the tables in the linked page though.  The US Navy seems to think that Brisbane and Sydney are in different timezones. :-)

Comment: Exponential notation of a float. Of course. Somebody could make that mistake. Seems like the most plausible explenation.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for previous misreading. I can confirm that .NET can't parse it, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        string x = "2010-12-21T08:55:17E-7+01:00";
        DateTime dt = SoapDateTime.Parse(x);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}
```

It looks like a bad SOAP service, to be honest. Looking at various bits of documentation around SOAP, it looks like SOAP date/time values *should* be `xsd:dateTime` values, which are formatted with ISO 8601 - and I can't see anything in the [Wikipedia ISO 8601 page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which would allow that. It's possible that Wikipedia is inaccurate, of course - but it's more likely that it's a bug in the SOAP service, IMO.

I suggest you look at the headers from the service to see if that gives a hint as to the underlying platform... then look for bugs reported against that platform producing invalid date/time values.

Comment: I wrote .NET has problems. Jax can parse it.

Comment: I dont't know the platform, but I suspect it's java

Comment: @Esben: Oops, sorry, I thought it said .NET had *no* problems parsing it. Will edit.